# Override Devise Sign-in with reCaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to override the Rails devise login to include recaptcha. I followed the steps here

http://presentations.royvandewater.com/authentication-with-devise.html#8

however for some reason, authentication always fails. To isolate the problem, I removed all my code and called super directly

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super
  end
end
```

file is at: Rails.root/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb the slide suggest Rails.root/app/controllers/sessions.rb but I assume that was just a mistake. Trying it out didn't help either.

I even copied the full Sessions Controller code into my own, still gives the problem. Authentication fails here specifically:

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What error messages are you getting with the authentication failure?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you could be doing wrong - not sure if this will help, but here's some other resources for setting up recaptcha with devise:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise

recaptcha:
  https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/

Here's how to do it on creation.  I imagine it's a similar approach for sign on, just override sessions controller like you are doing instead of registrations controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def create
     if session[:omniauth] == nil #OmniAuth
       if verify_recaptcha
         super
         session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record? #OmniAuth
       else
         build_resource
         clean_up_passwords(resource)
         flash[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code and click submit."
         render_with_scope :new
       end
     else
       super
       session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record? #OmniAuth
     end
   end
```

Comment: thanks. It's an old issue, no longer required but I will try it out if I need to.

Comment: the sign in controller might be different to this one